# grep -- list file name where match is found

Tags: command-line, grep

I have a bunch of .html files in a directory.  I want to look through each file and match a pattern (MD5).  All of that is easy enough.  The problem is I need to know what file the match was found in.

```
cat *.html | grep 75447A831E943724DD2DE9959E72EE31
```

Only returns the HTML page content where the match is found, but it doesn't tell me the file which it was found in.  How can I get grep to show me the filename where my match is found?

Comment: The provided suggestion really doesn't work....  All I get is 'standard input'                                                                cat *.html | grep -i -H 1ee024007823cc0bfbefba98ba1e1f4c
(standard input):<html><head><title>

Comment: you're missing the point. You don't need to use cat. The cat prevents grep from distinguishing individual files.

Comment: You might found useful [this Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637882/how-can-i-use-grep-to-show-just-filenames-no-in-line-matches-on-linux) post.

Answer (score 72):

```
grep -H 75447A831E943724DD2DE9959E72EE31 *.html
```

---

```
-H, --with-filename
              Print the file name for each match. This is
              the default when there is more than one file
              to search.
```

Answer (score 33):

I use this one all the time to look for files containing a string, RECURSIVELY in a directory (that means, traversing any sub sub sub folder)
`grep -Ril "yoursearchtermhere"`

- `R` is to search recursively (following symlinks)
- `i` is to make it case insensitive
- `l` is just to list the name of the files.

so answering your question
`grep -l '75447A831E943724DD2DE9959E72EE31' *.html` will do
but you can just do
`grep -Ril '75447A831E943724DD2DE9959E72EE31'` to look for that string, case insensitive, in any file in any subfolder

Comment: macOS requires a file def always, may it be a wildcard. Otherwise, it assumes input from `stdin` (_grep: warning: recursive search of stdin_, whatever recursive stdin input would mean :-). In other words: `grep -Ril 'texttofind' *`

Comment: `grep -RiH 'pattern'` shows files name and matched line

Answer (score 11):

You can try this

```
grep -rl '75447A831E943724DD2DE9959E72EE31' * > found.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

```
grep -r -H 75447A831E943724DD2DE9959E72EE31 *.html | awk -F : ' { print $1 } '
```

Alternative to

```
grep -r -l 75447A831E943724DD2DE9959E72EE31 *.html
```

Doing above will search recursively in the folder and subfolders and print the path of the file...

Answer (score 1):

The answer posted by Cyrus is absolutely proper and is The Right Way<sup>TM</sup> to do it with `grep` if we *only need to find files*. When filenames need to *additional parsing* or operations on the matched filenames, we can resort to using `while` loop with `if` statement. Here's an example where list of filenames comes from  very commonly used `find`+`while` structure for safe parsing of filenames.

```bsh
find -type f -name "*.html" -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' filename
do
    if grep -q 'PATTERN' "$filename"
    then
        printf "%s found in %s\n" 'PATTERN' "$filename"
        # Here we can insert another command or function
        # to perform other operations on the filename
    fi
done
```

Comment: Related: [Recursively search a pattern/text only in the specified file name of a directory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/867450/recursively-search-a-pattern-text-only-in-the-specified-file-name-of-a-directory), especially [muru's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/867560/22949) demonstrating `grep`'s `--include` flag.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```bsh
find . -type f -name=*.html -exec grep -H 75447A831E943724DD2DE9959E72EE31 {} \;
```