# The total size of the argument and environment lists 1.8MB exceeds the operating system limit of 2MB

Tags: command-line, 18.04, ram, fish

While trying to run certain commands via ubuntu terminal, I receives an error message

```
Failed to execute process '/bin/grep'. Reason:
The total size of the argument and environment lists 1.8MB exceeds the operating system limit of 2MB.
Try running the command again with fewer arguments.
```

The above error occured while I was trying to grep a string inside a folder via terminal.

I am using fish shell, with ubuntu 18.04 lts. Has 7.7 GiB RAM. OS type 64bit. GNOME 3.28.2 and has disk space with 34% used.

Comment: Maybe related to this link: https://codeyarns.com/2017/03/07/size-of-argument-and-environment-lists-exceeds-limit/ You could try combine with `find` command so the argument will not be a huge list.

Comment: Though I think this is *potentially* answerable as it stands, I recommend that you **[edit]** with the exact command you ran that produced the error. Then answers could explain the specific reason for the problem and how to work around it. [Argument list too long when copying files](https://askubuntu.com/q/217764) covers the general reason for this sort of error, but especially considering you're using `fish`--and that you're using `grep`, which [offers fine-grained control during recursive operation](https://askubuntu.com/a/867560)--I suspect this shouldn't be considered a duplicate of that.

Answer (score 0):

Incorrectly setting `PATH` environment variable might cause this error.

You should NOT add this line to config.fish. If you do, the variable will get longer each time you run fish!

See [issue](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/527)